# Cannot display blob image from database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, image, blob, phpactiverecord

I am not able to get my broswer to display an image from the database(stored as blob).  I have tried 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo '';

But it is still not able to display on the browser.

getImage.php

```
<?php
require_once 'php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
    $cfg->set_model_directory('models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array(
        'development' => 'mysql://root:mysql@localhost/BondingTogether'));
});

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$row = food::find_by_foodid($id);
$image = $row->image;
//$image = ""


//header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
//echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"/>';
echo $image;
//echo base64_decode($image);
```

Adding to the database

```
<?php

require_once 'php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg) {
    $cfg->set_model_directory('models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array(
        'development' => 'mysql://root:mysql@localhost/BondingTogether'));
});

//files
$file = $_FILES['foodimage']['tmp_name'];
if (!isset($file)) {
} 
else {
    //$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foodimage']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['foodimage']['tmp_name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['foodimage']['tmp_name']);

    if ($image_size == FALSE) {
        die('Please select an image file');
    } else {

    }
}
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foodimage']['tmp_name']));
//$image = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("image.jpg")));

Food::create(array(
    'xcoord' => $_POST['XCoord']
    , 'ycoord' => $_POST['YCoord']
    , 'title' => $_POST['title']
    , 'category' => $_POST['cat']
    , 'description' => $_POST['desc']
    , 'image' => $image
));
```

Comment: I have tried header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); and echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"/>';

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using addslashes() when storing image data in your DB. A better alternative is to insert the image data with base64_encode(), and base64_decode() it when you output it. A simple search will find plenty of good answers to this and similar questions

Comment: So it was the addslashes!! THANK YOU SO MUCH OMG!